# Divide by zero error(stored procedure)

Tags: sql

I have stored procedure with the following lines,

```
DECLARE @DateRun as datetime                                                               
Select @DateRun=LastRunDate from tblBatchRun where JobId = 1                               
INSERT INTO tblRawTestScore                                                                
select * from vwOverallTestScores where TimeCompleted > @DateRun
```

I now get an error like the one shown below,

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_CopyTestScoresRun, Line 9 Divide by
>   zero error encountered.

When I modify the above stored procedure lines like,

```
INSERT INTO tblRawTestScore                                                                
select * from vwOverallTestScores where TimeCompleted > (Select LastRunDate from tblBatchRun where JobId = 1)
```

my stored procedure now executes fine.

Can anybody help me on this pls?

Comment: You could run Profiler to get a trace of what exactly is happening on the scenario where you're getting divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like select lastrundate from tblbatchrun where jobid = 1 gets no rows.

In the first scenario you are getting a NULL result in your variable, which cannot be compared (it'll have problems casting things around as well), while in your second version the SP is not getting any results back from the subselect, therefore no comparison is made and no error is thrown.

Comment: I get Value in my variable(not NULL value).Eventhough the error is thrown.

Comment: What is the definition of vwOverallTestScores ?

Comment: I don't think a NULL result would have that effect. If @DateRun is null, then the "select ... where TimeCompleted > @DateRun" will just return no rows won't it?

Comment: As long as we don't get to see his view definition it'll be hard to tell what exactly is causing this, and it seems he's either figured it out or moved on. But there is a difference between having a NULL value in @DateRun compared to running the subquery. But then again, the divide by zero probably happens somewhere else in his view.

Answer (score 0):

What value are you getting from this statement:

Select LastRunDate from tblBatchRun where JobId = 1

Comment: DateTime value eg., 2010-11-08 08:51:20.017